# Proving set identities involving conditionals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

How can I prove the following conditional set identity?

For any three sets A, B, C we have $A\triangle(B\triangle C)=\varnothing \rightarrow(A\cup B\cup C)=((A\cap B)\setminus C)\cup((A\cap C)\setminus B)\cup((B\cap C)\setminus A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I prove the following conditional set identity?

A conditional proof involves *deriving the consequent* under the *assumption of the antecedent*.

Our *consequent* is an equality between sets.   These are derived by showing that each side of the equality is a subset of the other side.   That is done by demonstrating that any element in a subset is an element in the superset.

Our *antecedent* is $A\triangle (B\triangle C)=\varnothing$.   Using this requires applying the definition of symmetric difference, and identifying what it means for a set to be equal to the emptyset.